# Cheapest way to convert from toslink to 4 channel analog audio?

Tags: digital, analog

I have a mac-mini and an old [analog 4.1 set of speakers](http://images04.olx.pt/ui/11/46/88/1301001465_168863888_4-Colunas-Creative-PCWorks-41-Compra-Venda.jpg) and I want to use all 4 channels instead of only two.

I do not have a receiver and I am looking for the least expensive way of achieving 4 channels audio working.

I should also mention that the mac mini does have an HDMI out, so this could contain some audio out but I'm not sure how many channel it does have and I do know that my TV is not able to convert the signal to analog (and it's speakers are far worse than the 4.1 old system).

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/19831/1916

Answer (score 2):

I use a [Behringer ADA8000](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/ADA8000.aspx) for this - it converts toslink to 8 channels of analogue, and vice versa.  It works well, and is relatively inexpensive.